# SSRS 2012 y-axis interval expression MAX subject to multi-select parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, aggregate-functions, ssrs-2012

I trying to write an expression that sets the y-axis interval in my chart according to the maximum value shown in the chart. This is my current expression:

```
=IIF(MAX(Fields!itemcount.Value,"my_dataset")<=9,1,
CEILING(MAX(Fields!itemcount.Value,"my_dataset")*.4))
```

The problem is that this expression fails to maximize the itemcount field across a multi-select parameter called "store". So, if a user selects multiple stores when running the report, the axis interval is based on the maximum itemcount at the largest single store in the selection instead of the maximum itemcount across the aggregated itemcount of the stores selected.

Here is the query in my report that generates "my_dataset":

```
SELECT 
store,
SUM(item) as 'itemcount'
FROM mydata
WHERE store in (@store)
GROUP BY store
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dataset only has a Store and count, you should be able to use SUM instead of MAX:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!itemcount.Value,"my_dataset")<=9,1,
CEILING(SUM(Fields!itemcount.Value,"my_dataset")*.4))
```

Comment: Thanks Hannover Fist. I apologize: I oversimplified my dataset. There's a date field too, so it's a time series. SUM gives me the sum over the whole date range instead of the max value in the time series.